# Chrome extension network activity not showing up

Tags: google-chrome, networking, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, wireshark

I'm trying to identify API calls that a chrome extension is doing, but I am not seeing those in the network tab of Chrome (inspect->network).

Is there a way to mask those out from there? Should I use a different tool to identify the network activity?

Comment: If you remove the extension, can you see the network calls? Can you send a link or sample that shows the behavior?

Comment: Check the extension's [background console](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10258029/3930351)

Answer (score 2):

I guess you must be using **DevTools for Chrome** to debug you extension. In that case you can't see the network activities of your extension.

In order to debug you extension, you should use the **DevTools for Extension**:

Right click the extension icon, and you will see **Inspect the popup**, click that and select **Network** tab and you are done.

Like this(pay attention to the title of this):
[image]

For more infomation, you can see [Debugging of the chrome-extension tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tut_debugging). Hope this helps.